# How to format a date string with ordinal in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like below

'Jun 1st 2022, 8:30 am'

I needed to convert this into '2022-06-01T08:30'. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

use stringtime php function

```
$originalDate = "Jun 1st 2022, 8:30 am";
echo $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```